# Dynamic sheet creation using Aspose cells in Java?

Tags: java, xls, aspose-cells

I am using aspose-cells.jar for Excel export in my application.
I am stuck where I need to dynamically create sheets in the template.
My original Excel template contains 2 sheets.

1. Sheet1 contains the table and pie-chart.
2. Sheet2 contains the data for the table and pie-chart.

Depending upon the number of sample data selected these sheets has to be cloned i.e. Suppose two dates are selected then:

- Sheet1 should contain the graph and pie-chart for first date.
- Sheet2 should contain the graph and pie-chart for second date.

And

- Sheet3 should contain the data for first date.
- Sheet4 should contain the data for second date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Worksheets.addCopy method to clone an existing worksheet.

```
// Open the workbook
Workbook book = new Workbook(srcDoc);
boolean bSomeCondition = true;
// If some condition is true e.g. dates
if (bSomeCondition)
{
    // Copy first worksheet
    book.getWorksheets().addCopy("Sheet1");
    // Copy the second worksheet
    book.getWorksheets().addCopy("Sheet2");
}
// Save the workbook
book.save(dstDoc);
```